# problem with wordpress plugin repeating action

Tags: wordpress

I'm writing my first Wordpress plugin, and though not the most original one, I still cannot get it to work properly. The problem is that the function which echoes what needs to be echoed in the footer is doing it twice... to be precise, it echoes, then when it reads the add_action in the footer it repeats the action. Here's the code, if anyone knows where I'm missing it please let me know:

```
function add_copyright(){  
    $the_array = fof_check_db();
    $copyright_message = '<a href="' . $the_array[0] . '">' . $the_array[1] . '</a>';
    echo $copyright_message;
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'add_copyright');
```

Also, I tried changing the echo for return, but that didn't even display anything.

Any help will be welcomed

Comment: Seems like your theme is calling wp_footer() twice. Try going through the theme, and look for wp_footer calls.

Comment: thanks, that sounds plausible...but I'm just using the default theme for testing, I mean, even if it does call wp_footer, it is not calling the action, so what am I missing? (I don't know if I'm coming off rude or not, I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong here)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code from a general point of view. I tested it on wp-framework, and it worked fine. Where did you add the function and action hook?

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you're asking me. I did all my coding inside an only php file, created some options in the database, accessed those to get the array and only added this action on the wp_footer exec, is that where it's hooked?

Answer (score 1):

One explanation - if the theme isn't calling wp_footer() twice, is that your code that calls add_action() is being called twice.  That would add the action again and hence the wp_footer() code that calls do_action() would cause add_copyright() to be called twice - since any number of callbacks can be hooked into an action.
(That is perhaps the thinking behind @Frederik asking where you call add_action)