# jQuery "after" add div twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have problem where I want to add new div after specific div and this div is added twice:

```
<?php

add_action('wp_footer', 'myFunction');

function myFunction()
{

?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            var someVar = $(".product-total .woocommerce-Price-amount").html();
            $(
            ".order_item .woocommerce-Price-amount, .is-well .woocommerce-Price-amount "
            ).after(
            '<div class="price-wrapper eur"><div class="price">' +
                someVar +
                "</div></div>"
            ); 

        })

   
    </script>

 <?php

 }
```

Result is:

[image: markup]

jQuery is loaded once. This "after" is outside of loop. Even is only this jQuery line is in file is allways same result. With append is same situation.

this is happening on wordpress/woocommerce

Thanks for help,

A

Comment: I cannot reproduce this ~ https://jsfiddle.net/pk50artd/. What triggers your code to execute?

Comment: this is function in wphook:   add_action('wp_footer', 'myFunct'); and then document ready inside with this line of code. Some var is only html of price inside of td which is targeting

Comment: Can you include enough code to *reproduce* the problem?  The line by itself without any HTML context (so implied as in comment above) would not do cause this.

Comment: That's your server-side code. What triggers the jQuery in your question to run?

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852570/problem-with-wordpress-plugin-repeating-action) suggests your server-side `add_action` *may* be being called twice.

Comment: and [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84082/action-hook-wp-firing-twice-why) suggests it might happen if there's a (different) error elsewhere.

Comment: add debugger; inside after function
to trace what is calling it the second time

Comment: If I add code outside of function is working like it should ..thanks! I know where is problem

Comment: Provide the complete table HTML from the page source and create a code snippet to that it could be tested.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that I calling footer in template 2 times (wp_footer and get_footer) and because of that jQuery triggered twice.

Answer (score 0):

you can using append instead of after if you want to add a new element after an element
using these links for more information:

append:https://api.jquery.com/append/

appendTo:https://api.jquery.com/appendto/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).